# cannot get distinct values from table using hibernate

Tags: hibernate

i wanted to get distinct records from the table. but i always get only one recored. here is my code snippet, please suggest.

select distinct * from employee where employe_id=23567-- give me 3 records but below hibernate gives me only 1 record..

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(employee.class);
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("employeeid", Long.valueOf(employeeId.substring(0,7))));
        crit.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
        employeeList= crit.list();
        System.out.println("size--->"+employeeList.size());
```

i am i missing anything here ?

Comment: You get 3 records when searching by ID? Have you set a unique or PK constraint on the ID? Isn't that much stranger than what Hibernate returns? What's the SQL query generated by Hibernate? Are you sure you're on the same database and schema?

Comment: NO the coulms are defined as not null, the generated sql does not show any distinct clause as such... also it gives only one record always.

Comment: So, do you mean that you don't have any unique primary key in the table? If so, Hibernate won't work. Hibernate NEEDS unique immutable IDs.

Comment: ok, actually i get data into this table via flat file (not employee stuff i have just replace to hide my business logic)and its get dumped into it. so i can use a native sql query for this right..

Comment: No. A Hibernate entity MUST have a unique ID. If you don't have any unique and imutable column or set of columns in your table, you won't be able to use Hibernate. Why don't you add an auto-generated ID column?

Comment: ok i will try this and see how it works, thanks a ton JB :)

Comment: Thank J B Nizet, i could able to resolve this  based on your suggestions.